# Creating a Floating Widget that moves as the page scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, widget

All,
I'm using Wordpress widgets but I'd like to create a widget that floats down with the page as your scroll. Has anyone ever done anything like this? If so, can you give any recommendations on how to achieve such a widget? Is it done merely by Javascript/CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: Read about `position:fixed` http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slashnick's and maxedison's solutions will work.

If you'd like to have a dynamic scrolling box that doesn't always stay on the screen or minds the header, footer or any other div of your site, you might want to check out DropTheBit's sticky float jQuery plugin: http://dropthebit.com/74/sticky-floating-box/

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way - to install this new WordPress plugin - [Q2W3 Fixed Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/q2w3-fixed-widget/)

It was specifically designed for this purpose!

[Screenshots](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/q2w3-fixed-widget/screenshots/)

Comment: consider copying some of the content or explanation from the site, incase the link dies.

Comment: You need to disclose your affiliation with this plugin. Please see [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion)

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is set the position of the element in question to `fixed` via CSS, i.e.

```
.myFloatingWidget {position:fixed; left:0px; top:50%}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the widget a style of `position:fixed;`.  Example at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed).